# error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')

Tags: jss

I am setting up `JSS (NextJS)` application following https://miguelminoldo.fr/2021/10/18/deploying-sitecore-jss-next-vercel/

but when I run `jss create sitecoreverceldemo nextjs` I am getting the following error.
Any idea? is it to do with an incorrect version of the node?

```
3151 verbose stack     at TLSWrap.onerror (node:_tls_wrap:411:27)
3152 verbose cwd C:\templateProject\sitecoreverceldemo
3153 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19043
3154 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
3155 verbose node v16.13.1
3156 verbose npm  v8.1.2
3157 error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isServer')
3158 verbose exit 1
```